# New label prediction in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to build sentiment analysis using python. I have done model building part but facing challenge with new data set. I have already saved my model in pickle format. My original data set looks like (around 22 million rows is present)

```
text                                        category
product is good                                low
product is horrible                            high
it's not working properly                      high
quality wise good but still not happy          low
```

My new data set is -

```
text
i am a happy customer with this product
product quality is poor
sound is not good
overall its a good product
```

My final output looks like -

```
text                                                     category
i am a happy customer with this product                     low
product quality is poor                                     high
sound is not good                                           high
overall its a good product                                  low
```

My code looks like after basic cleaning -

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

nb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
               ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
              ])
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)

%%time
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_pred = nb.predict(X_test)

print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred,target_names=my_tags))

import pickle
print ("Model trained. Saving model to text_classification_NB1.pickle")
with open("text_classification_NB1.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(nb, file)
print ("Model saved.")
```

Now starts new prediction -

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/email/email_test_22122020.csv",encoding='latin1')
nb.predict(data)
```

But give me this results -

```
array(['low'], dtype='<U4')
```

Any help?

Comment: Help with *what*? Is there any issue? You gave a data sample, and you got a category (`'low'`). What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply `stemming` and remove `stop words` from your train and test datasets for better results. For more information [Removing stop words with NLTK in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/) and [Python | Stemming words with NLTK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-stemming-words-with-nltk/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try Data Cleaning techniques for text like lemmatization and stemming to ensure proper text is available for analysis. Also Remove Stop Words for avoiding unnecessary text.

You can try to find polarity of the sentence using TextBlob's [Sentiment Analysis](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#sentiment-analysis)